# Google play app downloading behavior

Tags: android, android-service

This may be most childish question but I really wanted to know that how is that working I mean When I starts the download , ends the app , and remove the app from task manager , but it still continue to downloading and shows progress in the status bar/notification bar.

I have made my app which is downloading something from the internet/server and showing progress in the notification bar/status bar , I am doing this in service and it starts downloading , when i destroy the activity it still continue to download , but when I remove the app from task manager the downloading stops , I can see that the progress in status bar also stops.

So how come the google app is managing this behavior and How can I make my app to download the things like google. ?

Any Idea and suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in your service to run your download it should run until the download is finished, even if you close or destroy the app before.

Comment: At least the `doInBackground( )` method should finish without being stopped.

Comment: but I do not know what makes it kill , you should try this

Comment: Do you test the app on a device? What exactly do you mean with removing the app from the task manager? Opening the overview and swiping it away?

Comment: yeah , i kill it in recent app process.

Comment: but when I press back button only , the download process goes all fine

Comment: Consider that the code in `onPostExecute( )` will not be executed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94780/discussion-between-coas-mckey-and-david145).